# There exist no natural number n such that $\frac1n=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that there exist no natural number n such that $\frac1n=0$

My Solution.
Suppose there exist a natural number $n$ such that $\frac1n=0$

I claim that $$\frac1n \in P$$ (where $0$ is not in $P$)

If not then $$-\frac1n \in P \text{ or } -\frac1n \in 0$$ multiplying by $n$ we get $$-1 \in P\text{ or } -1=0$$ 
First case is impossible since $1 \in P$ and if it is true then $1+ \left(-1\right)=0 \in P$

For the second case equivalently $$1=0$$ which is again a contradiction.

Am I Correct?

How do I show that there exists no real number such that $$\frac1n=0$$

Comment: What is $P{{}}$?

Comment: This is very heavily dependent on what hypothesis you have access to in order to prove this result.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown here set P is subset the ordered field sattisfying $x,y \in P$ then $x+y,xy \in P$

Comment: Whay can't you just say that $1/n=0$ implies the contradiction $0n=1$?